Distribute parallel strips on object surface wit UVs
I need to create a procedural setup that allows me to create surfaces as in the example image. Basically it is parallel strips or lamellas that are attached to a garment mesh on one of the longer side.
Does anyone have ideas how to
a) create those strips on a complex mesh that will be animated
b) make sure that the lower end of the strip moves away from the base mesh to get a 3D effect that is more accurate than using a simple displacement workflow
c) how to apply UVs so that I can texture the strips.
The reason I need this to be procedural is that I need the option to change the angle, thickness, spacing, texture.
Thanks already for making it this far and for any help or suggestions!
Best
T

This is in no way a precise suggestion but the wave texture is maybe an option for the stripes.
